# pre-order traversal of a Minimum spanning tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, minimum-spanning-tree, preorder

Is there any way to print the pre-order traversal of the output given by MST (using Kruskal or Prim's algorithm). I have a confusion because the output may be or not a binary tree always. So, how the pre-order traversal is possible here? Can a normal DFS  do the task?

Answer (score 6):

The main issue when working with this kind of problem is the ambiguity of the word *tree* in algorithmic problems. There are two main definitions (those may in fact differ slightly):

1. A tree is an acyclic connected (undirected) graph.
2. A tree is basically a set of nodes, each one having a father (except one node, called the *root* node) and the list of sons for each node is ordered.

However, you have to work with the second definition to assume that the concept of *preoder traversal* is well-defined (i.e. unique).

A spanning tree, though, is only a tree in the first meaning. In particular, you have to pick out a root node and some order for the sons. Afterwards, a DFS will give you a preoder traversal indeed.